# Azure Active Directory causes JWT token to be ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, azure-active-directory

I'm using `BearerTokenAuthentication`.

In the `Azure Portal` I activated `Azure Active Directory` to prevent third parties to access the website I deploy.

But when activating the `Active Directory` feature, Azure appends a `Cookie` to every request, which causes the ClaimsPrincipal to contain data from that cookie of Active Directory instead of data that is contained in the Bearer Token I send with it.

This is how I discovered that the principal is not gathered from the Bearer token:

```
[RoutePrefix("users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("me/claims")]
    public IHttpActionResult Me()
    {
        var caller = (ClaimsPrincipal)User;
        return Ok(caller.Claims.Select(claim => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(claim.Type, claim.Value)));
    }
}
```

These are the request headers:

```
accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
authorization:Bearer [Token]
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:ARRAffinity=[AzureActiveDirectoryToken]
```

How can I make sure that the only authentication mechanism used, is the `Bearer Token`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your web api config

`config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();`

to ignore the cookie, and

`config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter("Bearer"));`

to activate the bearer authentication type.

Comment: Thank you for your anwer, I will try this out shortly.

Comment: I tried it but the only thing that happens is, that some kind of redirect happens over and over again now.